# How to fix this error in my appsync while creating an array of data

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync, vtl

I am creating an array of date and in my resolver it only return one output of date and count audited

I search throughout the google to find some answer and I found a code how to make an array of list but the problem is it didn't return well

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcRHc.jpg
this is a result and the code I use it attached in the picture

```
#set ($tu = 0) #set ($pc = 0) #set ($fc = 0) #set ($da = [])#set ($cda = [])                                                                  #foreach($item in $ctx.result.items)
#set($tu = $item.total_audits + $tu)
#set($pc = $item.passed_compliance + $pc)
#set($fc = $item.failed_compliance + $fc)
#set($date = $item.sort)
#set($count = $item.total_audits)
$util.qr($da.add("$date"))
$util.qr($cda.add("$count"))
#end
$util.toJson({"total_audits":$tu, "passed_compliance":$pc,
"failed_compliance":$fc, "daily_audit": [{"date": $da, "count": $cda}]})
```

here is the error

```
 "errors": [
{
  "path": [
    "getAuditSummary",
    "daily_audit",
    0,
    "date"
  ],
  "locations": null,
  "message": "Can't serialize value (/getAuditSummary/daily_audit[0]/date) : Unable to serialize `[2018-12-26, 2018-12-27, 2018-12-28]` as a valid date."
},
{
  "path": [
    "getAuditSummary",
    "daily_audit",
    0,
    "count"
  ],
  "locations": null,
  "message": "Can't serialize value (/getAuditSummary/daily_audit[0]/count) : Expected type 'Int' but was 'ArrayList'."
```

what i want to make is it would return something like this

```
 "daily_audit": [
        {
          "date": 2018-12-26,
          "count": 1
        }
        {
          "date": 2018-12-27,
          "count": 4
        }
        {
          "date": 2018-12-28,
          "count": 2
        }
]
```

Comment: Hi Jhomz, and welcome on Stackoverflow. Could you please copy your code from the picture you posted into this post? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because `$da` and `$cda` are arrays. So it's probably returning:

```
"daily_audit": [
    {
      "date": [2018-12-26,2018-12-27,2018-12-28],
      "count": [1,4,2]
    }
]
```

So, in your response mapping template, you can try something like:

```
#set ($tu = 0) 
#set ($pc = 0) 
#set ($fc = 0) 
#set ($da = [])                                                          

#foreach($item in $ctx.result.items)
    #set($tu = $item.total_audits + $tu)
    #set($pc = $item.passed_compliance + $pc)
    #set($fc = $item.failed_compliance + $fc)
    #set($date = $item.sort)
    #set($count = $item.total_audits)
    $util.qr($da.add({"date":$date, "count":$count}))
#end
$util.toJson({"total_audits":$tu, "passed_compliance":$pc, "failed_compliance":$fc, "daily_audit": $da})
```

Comment: how to get the some items and data from my dynamoDB table setup
   | id     |     sort    | survey_1 | survey_2 | survey_3 |
    --------------------------------------------------------
   |waklo   | 2018-12-28  |    4     |    5     |    5     |
 
what I want to get survey_1, survey_2 survey_3 and its corresponding value I am using vtl for aws resolver
to make something like this 
tally : [
   {
     id: survey_1
     total: 4
   }
   {
     id: survey_2
     total: 5
   }
   {
     id: survey_3
     total: 5
   }
]

Comment: thank you very much @Lisa it works and solve my problem